# What is this variable-length integer encoding?

Tags: encoding, integer, variable-length, 8-bit

I am documenting an old file format and have stumped myself with the following issue.

It seems to be that integers are variable-length encoded, with numbers <= `0x7F` encoded in a single byte, but >= `0x80` are encoded in two bytes. An example set of integers and their encoded counterparts:

- `0x390` is encoded as `0x9007`
- `0x150` is encoded as `0xD002`
- `0x82` is encoded as `0x8201`
- `0x89` is encoded as `0x8901`

I have yet to come across any numbers that are larger than `0xFFFF`, so I can't be sure if/how they are encoded. For the life of me, I can't work out the pattern here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At a glance it looks like the numbers are split into 7-bit chunks, each of which is encoded as the 7 least significant bits of an output byte, while the most significant bit signifies whether there are more bytes following this one (i.e. the last byte of an encoded integer has 0 as its MSB).

The least significant bits of the input come first, so I guess you could call this "little endian".

Edit: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity (this is used in MIDI and Google protocol buffers)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your help; now it seems so obvious, I feel silly for not seeing it earlier!